# How is testify/assert.Contains used with a map?

Tags: unit-testing, go, assert

the [docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert#Contains) show this as an example:

`assert.Contains(t, {"Hello": "World"}, "Hello", "But {'Hello': 'World'} does contain 'Hello'")`

But running this fails

```
mymap := map[string]string{}
mymap["Hello"] = "World"
assert.Contains(t, mymap, "Hello")
```

results in the error:

`Error:     "map[Hello:World]" could not be applied builtin len()`

switching mymap and "hello" results in this:

`Error:     "Hello" does not contain "map[Hello:World]"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I checked that and it works fine to me. Are you sure that the displayed error is related to that code? That's what I tried:

```
package main

import "testing"
import "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"

func TestContains(t *testing.T) {
    mymap := map[string]string{}
    mymap["Hello"] = "World"
    assert.Contains(t, mymap, "Hello")
}
```

And the test doesn't fail:

```
→ go test stackoverflow/35387510/contains_test.go
ok      command-line-arguments  0.009s
```

Comment: Weird.   If I run just your file it works.  If I run your file via my make file with other tests, it fails with that error (which does come from assert.Contains).   Something in my environment must be getting corrupted either by the makefile or the other tests.   All the other assert.* functions work ok, though.

Comment: Could you provide us with your test file and the makefile? Just to reproduce it on our side.

Comment: get docker-machine from github and drop the test file into drivers/virtualbox.  Run `make test`.    https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md  I just double checked with a fresh copy off master to make sure I didn't introduce something.  Still fails.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you must be using type assertion

```
package main

import "testing"
import "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"

func TestContains(t *testing.T) {
     // Initialize assert as below
    assert := assert.New(t)
    mymap := map[string]string{}
    mymap["Hello"] = "World"
    //then no need to pass t in contains
    assert.Contains(mymap, "Hello")
}
```

In [docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/assert) which for contains in type assertions